# Installing MS SQL Server 2012 during application installation

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-installer, installation, setup-project, msi-patch

There is this financial application which its man executive file is written by Delphi language. Im working on its setup project. it has so many steps. the most confusing required step is installing MS SQL Server with custom condition. so im just wondering if it is doable to install MS SQL Server 2012 ( **Standard edition or higher** ) during my application setup?

Comment: No, you won't be able to install a Microsoft-licensed piece of software directly along with your app. This will have to be done by the customer before installing your application.

Comment: thank you for your response.
how about MS SQL Server 2012 express version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install the express edition of SQL server alongside your application setup. You should just add it as a prerequisite to your setup package.